# Eclipse Marketplace ValidatorException (PKIX)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-marketplace, pkix

I recently moved to a new machine at work. So I downloaded the latest Java/Eclipse and all other stuff. But I need to download two or three plugins and the trouble is, I keep getting this error:

```
Unable to read repository at https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/subclipse/4.3.x/content.xml.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I see that it is a common error. But did not find a solution that was posted online. Can you please help with this.

Comment: Maybe you have an old JDK version that does not support the digicert used by that site. Try running your JDK with a later version or add the root certificate manually to your keystore: https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO20462.html

Comment: Its the latest, u241. Downloaded it just 4 hours ago.

Comment: https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/subclipse/4.3.x/content.xml gives a 404 error when I try it. Does your new machine have all of its O.S. updates installed?

Comment: Yeah, it does. Its a brand new install. Only thing is the Eclipse is new. and the JDK. Previously I was using u202 on my older machine.

Comment: I was able to get the Subclipse plugin installted by downloading the zip file from the URL and installing it. But the original problem still remains with other plugins. I tried the guide above. Didn't solve the issue.